# Regular Expression (JavaScript) to create a data validation where the number must be more than x

Tags: javascript, html, database, validation

I am trying to write a regular expression using javascript in order to validate data entry on an online database. I have attached a screenshot ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCUMa.png)) of the page which is asking me to do this. The question I am asking is what is the weight? The validation I am trying to create is that it needs to be more than 24 kg. I am complete novice at JS (I have good experience with SQL) and have been reading  *developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Writing_a_Regular_Expression_Pattern* and 
w*ww.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp*

I have tried a few things and tested them on rubular but to no avail.

Any advice would be much appreciated and in the meantime I will continue reading.

Many thanks, 
Jenna

Comment: For the input field just set type="number" min="24".

Comment: Thank you for your response but when I tried that I received the following message: unless the value entered matches the pattern: type="number" min="24"
Should be a regular expression

Comment: We appear to be missing your screenshot

Comment: Thank you SpoonMeiser. I  have edited the main post and checked that this now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, this sounds the sort of situation for which a regular expression is not a reasonable choice for validation. Just comparing numbers would make much more sense.

However, a regular expression that would match a number greater than or equal to 24 would be:

```
/^(\d{3,}|[3-9]\d|2[4-9])$/
```

That is, it matches one of:

- `\d{3,}` a number at least 3 digits long
- `[3-9]\d` a number in the range 30 - 99
- `2[4-9]` a number in the range 24 - 29

To match only greater than 24, just change the last alternative:

```
/^(\d{3,}|[3-9]\d|2[5-9])$/
```

Comment: Thank you that has solved it, and thank you also for your explanation I am sure this will help me learn.

Comment: thanks again for your help. I have worked with what you have kindly provide above to try and make another validation where the number has to be between 34-44. I tried /^[4-4]\d|3[4-9]$/ but with this the maximum number I can enter is 49. Any ideas? Thanks again so much!

Comment: `/^(3[4-9]|4[0-4])$/`

Comment: That is: either 34-39 or 40-44

Comment: I your attempt, `[4-4]\d` means two digits, the first in the rang 4-4 (ie 4) followed by any digit. Hence `[4-4]` matches 4 and `\d` matches 9, which wasn't what you wanted.